# html css navigator bar blocking the width of image slider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple website using HTML and CSS as i am beginner-level to programming. The problem is that my image slider is shifting from the right side because of div `class="toggle`" when i set it to `display:block` in CSS and when i set its height to 100% it gets fix. i want to know the reason that is causing it..

**HTML:**

```
    <nav>
        <div id="navigator">
        <ul class="parent-nav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><span><a href="#">Menu1</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#">Menu2</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#">Menu3</a></span>
        <ul class="child-nav">
        <li><span><a href="#">test1</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="#">test2</a></span></li></ul></li>
        <li><span><a href="#">Menu4</a></span></li></ul>
        <div class="toggle"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">&#9776;</a></div>
         </div>
    </nav>

<section>
    <div id="slider">
         <div class="slider-container">
              <div class="sider-image slid1">
                   <div class="silder-content">
                   <h4>Title 1</h4>
                   <p>test test test test..... </p>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="sider-image slid2">
                   <div class="silder-content">
                       <h4>Title 2</h4>
                       <p>test test testtest test.....</p>
                   </div>
              </div>            
         </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navigator{
    background: url("../image/navbg.gif") repeat-x  center ;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px; 
}

.parent-nav{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

.parent-nav > li{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 100px;
}

.parent-nav > li > span{

}

.parent-nav > li > span > a{    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
}

.toggle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%; /*when i remove this my image slider shifts form right */
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
}

.toggle > a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px 34px 12px 34px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
    display: block;
}

.toggle > a.icon{
    display: block;
}  
#slider{
    height: 300px;
    border: #1F1F1F 20px solid;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

#slider > .slider-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: animate 20s infinite;
    z-index: -1;
}

.slider-container > .sider-image{
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    float:left;
}

.slider-container > .sider-image > .silder-content{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: 0.5s;

}

.slider-container > .sider-image > .silder-content > h4{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.slider-container > .sider-image > .silder-content > p{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: `myfunction` is missing in your code

Comment: You should consider making a https://stackblitz.com/ example so people can more easily reproduce the issues you're seeing. However, I see you have a `position: absolute` but then are positioning items using `float`. I suspect that is playing a role in your problem